# Cannot find the reference specified-Visual Basic 2013

Tags: vb.net, object, reference

I've got a new system. I am trying to connect to and run the system through a 64-bit Windows 7 PC. The company sent me a Visual Basic project for that. It uses .NET framework 4 and Windows Form Applications. The target CPU is x86.

In the References tab, next to three of the COM references there are "The system cannot find the reference specified" statements. When built, the project gives the namespace errors and warnings because of these objects. The other references work fine. I've then seen those .dll files in the debug folder. I think they are generated by the company before sending me. They also exist in the bin\debug folder.

I've removed the three from the references list in the project and tried the following separately:

1) In the project, refer to the .dll files that exist in the debug folder. (Seems a fake way, but removes all the errors when the project is built. When debug, it gives the "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID ... failed due to the following error: 80040154" error.)

2) Copy the .dll files in the debug folder to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder, then register through regsvr32 "name.dll" in the console as admin. This way, I get the ".dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found" error. (In the regedit window, the registry editor cannot find the ID's of those references that are seen in the project properties in VB.)

3) Do the item (2), but with the C:\Windows\System32 folder instead of SysWOW64. The same error when registering.

4) Changed the solution platform to x86 and tried the items 1,2, and 3. Still the same errors.

Do I have to register these dll files? And, am I supposed to register exactly these dll files that exist in the debug folder? Or are they supposed to be generated after build by referring to some 'missing' type libraries in the references tab? I don't have these type libraries, though.

All suggestions are welcome ASAP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be hardcoded paths to the DLL files. You should collect them in some "reference folder" and use this folder to reference the DLL files. You can check this by editing the project file, it is simple XML. I wouldn't register the DLL's, it might bring you in a lot of trouble with automated builds and deployment.

Comment: @Styxxy To clarify it: These are Interop DLLs. How can I find their normal DLLs so I can add them to the references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three Interop dlls for your project, correct? These dlls just allow you to use a COM dll without having to talk directly to the COM dlls yourself.

Referencing the dlls in the bin/Debug directory should be fine, since those are probably the correct dlls that the project was built with. However, you will want to move them to another folder before continuing.

What you need to get from the company that sent you the project is the original COM dlls and their dependencies, if any. Usually an interop dll is called Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll where it is performing interop with Microsoft.Phone.dll. Microsoft.Phone.dll needs to be registered on your computer using regsvr32 and then you just need a reference to the interop dll.

Comment: Oh my, yes. Updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. The company did not send to me those .dlls at all. As you said, referencing to the Interop.dlls was fine, and they prevented build errors. Then, at the debug step, I had the error I wrote in the item 1. I then followed this: http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/
and the problem went away, the code started working. What this link does is just adding the reference with this specific CLSID to the registry library of the PC. Thanks again.